# Ionic 2 image not showing in Android phone

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am writing an ionic app with a .gif background and some images placed in ion-img:

```
    <ion-img src="/assets/img/logo.png" width="100%" height="147px" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)" class="home-page-img"></ion-img>
```

When I test the app in web browser, it works fine, however when I test it to android phone, the images are not shown. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'assets/img/logo.png' path works fine in app and web browser.

```
src="assets/img/logo.png"
```